# relation of Gaussian and mean curvature to laplacian and hessian

Tags: differential-geometry

> The mean curvature $H$ and Gaussian curvature $K$ of the two
>   dimensional surface $z=f(x,y)$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are
>
> $(a)$ $H=\nabla^2f$, $K=$ determinant of Hessian of $f$.
>
> $(b)$ $H=$ determinant of Hessian of $f$, $K=\nabla^2f$.
>
> $(c)$ $H=\nabla^2f$, $K=$ Hessian of $f$.
>
> $(d)$ $H=$ Hessian of $f$, $K=\nabla^2f$.

I know that here $\displaystyle K=\frac{f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2}{(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^2}=\frac{\text{determinant of hessian of }f}{(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^2}$. So I can't directly tell that $K=$ determinant of Hessian of $f$ in this case because of the denominator. I cannot also understand whether $H=$ average of the principal curvatures $=\nabla^2f$. Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did this multiple choice question come from? You're correct that none of these is correct.

Comment: From an examination paper. Don't know whoever sets wrong questions to waste valuable time.

Comment: Maybe change the question to assume you're at a critical point of $f$. Still, there's the issue of the factor of $1/2$ in the mean curvature. Some skip that.

Comment: Means mean curvature is the Laplacian? How? I couldn't get that also.

Comment: The second fundamental form is given (maybe with a factor of $1/2$) by the Hessian matrix, assuming the gradient vanishes, and the trace of the Hessian is the Laplacian.